# button initialization in other function instead of OnCreate() method

Tags: java, android

Can we define a function in OnCreate method which can be used to initialize buttons and all other widgets. I have tried the following but I am getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference error

```
package com.conceptkillers.www.electromania1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;

/**
 * Created by Nikesh on 11/02/2016.
 */
public class OhmsLawActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int checkedCount = 0;
    LinearLayout vlayout,ilayout,rlayout,playout;
    CheckBox checkBox1,checkBox2,checkBox3,checkBox4;
    Spinner spinnerV,spinnerI,spinnerR,spinnerP;
    EditText edittextv,edittexti,edittextr,edittextp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setTitle("Ohms Law");
        InitializeAllWidgets();

    }

    public void InitializeAllWidgets() {

        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_v);
        checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_i);
        checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_r);
        checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_p);

        edittextv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_v);
        edittexti = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_i);
        edittextr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_r);
        edittextp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_p);

        String[] valuesVoltageSpinner = {"YV","ZV","EV","PV","TV","GV","MV","KV"
                ,"V","mV","uV","nV","pV","fV","aV","zV","yV"};
        String[] valuesCurrentSpinner = {"YA","ZA","EA","PA","TA","GA","MA","KA"
                ,"A","mA","uA","nA","pA","fA","aA","zA","yA"};
        String[] valuesResistanceSpinner = {"YOhm","ZOhm","EOhm","POhm","TOhm","GOhm","MOhm","KOhm"
                ,"Ohm","mOhm","uOhm","nOhm","pOhm","fOhm","aOhm","zOhm","yOhm"};
        String[] valuesPowerSpinner = {"YW","ZW","EW","PW","TW","GW","MW","KW"
                ,"W","mW","uW","nW","pW","fW","aW","zW","yW"};

        spinnerV = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_v);
        spinnerI = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_i);
        spinnerR = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_r);
        spinnerP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_p);

        ArrayAdapter<String> voltageAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valuesVoltageSpinner);
        voltageAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinnerV.setAdapter(voltageAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> currentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valuesCurrentSpinner);
        currentAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinnerI.setAdapter(currentAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> resistanceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valuesResistanceSpinner);
        resistanceAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinnerR.setAdapter(resistanceAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> powerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valuesPowerSpinner);
        powerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinnerP.setAdapter(powerAdapter);

        checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                handleCheckBox1();
            }
        });

        checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                handleCheckBox2();
            }
        });

        checkBox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                handleCheckBox3();
            }
        });

        checkBox4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                handleCheckBox4();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onButtonClicked(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.simple_voltage:
                checkBox1.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
                checkBox2.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkBox3.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkBox4.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkedCount = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.simple_current:
                checkBox1.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkBox2.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
                checkBox3.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkBox4.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkedCount = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.simple_resistance:
                checkBox1.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkBox2.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkBox3.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
                checkBox4.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkedCount = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.simple_power:
                checkBox1.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkBox2.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkBox3.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkBox4.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
                checkedCount = 0;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void handleCheckBox1() {

        if(checkedCount < 2) {

            if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                checkedCount++;
                edittextv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinnerV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                checkedCount--;
                edittextv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                spinnerV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    }

    private void handleCheckBox2() {

        if(checkedCount < 2) {
            if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                checkedCount++;
                edittexti.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinnerI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                checkedCount--;
                edittexti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                spinnerI.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleCheckBox3() {

        if(checkedCount < 2) {
            if (checkBox3.isChecked()) {
                checkedCount++;
                edittextr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinnerR.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                checkedCount--;
                edittextr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                spinnerR.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleCheckBox4(){

        if(checkedCount < 2) {
            if (checkBox4.isChecked()) {
                checkedCount++;
                edittextp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinnerP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                checkedCount--;
                edittextp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                spinnerP.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Question Title is totally different then your question details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `setContentView`

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

Comment: And can we use functions like I have used in the above code InitializeAllWidgets?

Comment: yes, you can use the function InitializeAllWidgets the way you've used it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set any layout to your activity. Use setContentView(int layoutId) in your code which will attach the layout to which these widgets (spinners) belong.

The rest of the code seems fine. And by that I mean you can have a method that initializes the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code and add your layout

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContectView(R.layout.view);

        this.setTitle("Ohms Law");
        InitializeAllWidgets();

    }
```